# Angular UI Router animation on parent view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have a nested state like:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: '/contacts',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateURL: 'views/contacts.html',
            contacts: 'ContactsCtrl'
        }
    }
})
.state('contacts.view', {
    url: '/contacts/:name',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateURL: 'views/contacts-details.html'
        }
    }
});
```

contacts.html

```
<section id="contacts-list">
    <h1>This is a list of contacts</div>
    <article class="contacts" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">(...)</article>
    <ui-view/>
</section>
```

contacts-view.html

```
<h2>{{ contact.name }}</h2>
```

I'm able to animate the contacts-view.html ng-enter and ng-leave events but what I wanted was to animate the #contacts-list container in order to make a slide to right effect.

What would be the proper way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: When would you like the animation to happen?

Comment: when the child state is entered but I want to trigger the animation on the parent. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

Replace contacts-view.html with:

```
<section id="contacts-list">
    <h1>This is a list of contacts</div>
    <article class="contacts" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">(...)</article>
    <h2>{{ contact.name }}</h2>
</section>
```

and in your contacts.html write:

```
<section id="contacts-list" ui-view>
    <h1>This is a list of contacts</div>
    <article class="contacts" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">(...)</article>
</section>
```

That should do the trick if you don't mind code repetition in your templates.

Edit:

I understand now what you want to do a bit more:

What about:

```
<section id="contacts-list" ng-class="{ detail: $state.is('contacts.view')>
    <h1>This is a list of contacts</div>
    <article class="contacts" ng-repeat="contact in contacts">(...)</article>
    <ui-view />
</section>
```

And then you add the add/remove animation classes to the detail class. That should work without the need of repetition or adding/removing unnecessary elements to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Wawy. That doesn't sound like a good approach though. Besides not being maintainable it has a performance overweight as you're duplicating calls amongst other things.

Comment: I know, but if you want to animate the parent state you are going to have to redraw those elements on the DOM which will mean duplicating calls.

Comment: Well, you could listen to state changes among other things... I just wanted to know what was considered the best practice as I think this is pretty interesting for responsive design for instance.

Comment: Yes, you could. I'm just curious of why would you want to animate the collection when accessing an individual? Would you like to hide the collection while you are in the individual?

Comment: But should I?:) The reason is that I want a design pattern like reading pane on tablets/desktop but a slide from left to right on mobile. I can just slide in the child view (which is what I'm currently doing) but then I still need to disable scrolling on the parent view and dimm it... Any idea for this use case?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect what you meant. Does that work for you?

Comment: That looks really clean. Love it. Will try and come back to you. Thansk